# How to access data attribute?

Tags: twig

I have a button with `aria-expanded` attribute. Depending on its state, I want to render a different icon in the template. How can I achieve it? I don't know how to target / read the "aria-expanded" attribute itself by using Twig. This is the effect that I want to get

```
<button aria-expanded="false">
    {% if aria-expanded="false" %}
        [ render icon 1 here]
    {% else %}
        [render icon 2 here]
    {% endif %}
</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is`aria-expanded`? Is it a variable?

Comment: `aria-expanded` is the accessibility attribute suggesting an element is opened. I have found an answer already - the solution that I want to achieve is not possible inside of the Twig templates. It needs to be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Please don't use the question to add an answer